# simple javascript question

Tags: javascript, iframe

```
document.getElementById("myFrame").setAttribute("src") = "http://www.yahoo.com/";
```

myFrame is an iframe element... when entering this into the chrome developer console, it gives me the error "Invalid left-hand side in assignment"  I am trying to update the iframe.  Is there a method I am forgetting?

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.setAttribute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, I fixed it

```
document.getElementById("myFrame").setAttribute("src", "http://www.yahoo.com/");
```

Answer (score 3):

[`setAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.setAttribute) takes two arguments:

```
document.getElementById("myFrame").setAttribute("src", "http://www.yahoo.com/");
```

You are trying to set the DOM object to the string `"http://www.yahoo.com/"` ... which is invalid.

Answer (score 3):

You don't really need `setAttribute` when setting the `src` property:

```
document.getElementById('myFrame').src = 'http://www.yahoo.com/';
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't assign an function call to something, try this instead:

```
document.getElementById("myFrame").setAttribute("src", http://www.yahoo.com/");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
document.getElementById("myFrame").setAttribute("src","http://www.yahoo.com/");
```